# Run the javascript code when viewport change in sencha rouch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, viewport, onload-event

I have some javascript code that need to be run when the new page is load. But the onload event just first only one time when the application start. When I change viewport with animateActiveItem, the event not fire. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `activeitemchange` event in the `Viewport`: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-event-activeitemchange

```
Ext.Viewport.on('activeitemchange', function(viewport, newPanel, oldPanel) {
    //do whatever here
}
```